# Sys.UI.DomElment.getLocation returns different values in Google Chrome than in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

I'm having some troubles with my canvas element in google chrome.

I have a canvas with multiple rectangles on it. I keep track of the rectangles in an array named targets. Every time the mouse moves over the canvas, I call the hover function to check if the mouse is on top of one of the rectangles.

If it's on top of a rectangle, the rectangle should be filled with a solid color.

Look at this javascript line:

```
function hover() {
    var location = Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation(canvasElement);

    // loop through all rectangles in the targets array and caluclate if the mouse is on top op any of these rectangles.
}
```

This works fine in IE and firefox.

But in google chrome, the rectangles are filled when i hover in the area, of the same dimensions as the rectangle, above the rectangle.

Because it's always the same distance above the actual position of the rectangle, I soon found out that the **Sys.UI.DomElement getLocation** method returns different values in Google Chrome.

Here are the results:

Firefox:

```
var location = Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation(canvasElement);

location.x = 545
location.y = 297
```

Chome:

```
var location = Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation(canvasElement);

location.x = 544
location.y = 94
```

So there's 1 pixel in the horizontal direction and a bit more than 200 pixels in the vertical direction.

Now i know how it come that my rectangles are filled when i hover in the area above the rectangles.

But of course i want to know what i should do to avoid this behavior with google chrome.

Do you have any idea?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

More info:

MSDN: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397695.aspx)

> Sys.UI.DomElement getLocation Method
>
> Gets the absolute position of a DOM element relative to the upper-left
>   corner of the owner frame or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution using JQuery:

var location = $(canvasElement).offset();

Then just use location.left and location.top